# Convert Yaml to Sorted Json data in Terraform

Tags: json, sorting, yaml, terraform

How can we create a sorted JSON file from a yaml datasource in Terraform.

I have a yaml file with similar data as below

```
users:
  - key: 'user[0].name'
    value: Roku
  - key: 'user[0].age'
    value: '55'
  - key: 'user[0].city'
    value: rome
  - key: 'user[1].name'
    value: Andy
  - key: 'user[1].age'
    value: '22'
  - key: 'user[1].city'
    value: madrid
```

From the above file I am trying to create a SORTED json data based on AGE value using terraform local as below

```
{
  "rome": [
    {
      "name": "Andy",
      "age": 22
    }
  ],
  "madrid": [
    {
      "name": "Roku",
      "age": 55
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such thing as "SORTED json" and terraform map does not have order anyway. So you have to forget about "sorted" TF map, or change your output variable.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do and why you can't have sorted json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, you can't have "sorted" json nor TF map. So your map (without any order) can be obtained using:

```
variable "yaml" {

  default = <<EOL
users:
  - key: 'user[0].name'
    value: Roku
  - key: 'user[0].age'
    value: '55'
  - key: 'user[0].city'
    value: rome
  - key: 'user[1].name'
    value: Andy
  - key: 'user[1].age'
    value: '22'
  - key: 'user[1].city'
    value: madrid
  - key: 'user[2].name'
    value: Andyaa
  - key: 'user[2].age'
    value: '222'
  - key: 'user[2].city'
    value: madrid
  - key: 'user[10].name'
    value: Doon
  - key: 'user[10].age'
    value: '55'
  - key: 'user[10].city'
    value: rome  
  - key: 'user[10].gender'
    value: F    
EOL

}



locals {
    yaml_decoded = yamldecode(var.yaml)
    
    cities =  {for user_property in local.yaml_decoded.users:
               regex("\\[(\\d+)\\]", user_property.key)[0] =>   user_property.value if split(".", user_property.key)[1] == "city"
              }
}



output "test" {
  value = {for idx, city in local.cities:
       city => merge([
          for user_property in local.yaml_decoded.users:
            {
              split(".", user_property.key)[1] = try(tonumber(user_property.value), user_property.value),
            } if (idx  == regex("\\[(\\d+)\\]", user_property.key)[0] 
                  &&
                  split(".", user_property.key)[1] != "city")
       ]...)... 
      }
}
```

gives:

```
test = {
  "madrid" = [
    {
      "age" = 22
      "name" = "Andy"
    },
    {
      "age" = 222
      "name" = "Andyaa"
    },
  ]
  "rome" = [
    {
      "age" = 55
      "name" = "Roku"
    },
    {
      "age" = 55
      "gender" = "F"
      "name" = "Doon"
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: This feels rather heroic for a situation I would question doing in Terraform at all instead of a pre-proc or post-proc wrapper, so +1 if nothing else for the effort.

Comment: @MattSchuchard This is generic code. It works with more cases than OP's example (various order of items, conversions of strings to numbers, optional records like gender). But I agree, to make it work with the only example provided by OP, it could be simpler.